# Is this type of border-image possible?

Tags: border

I've used CSS border-image successfully in the past, but usually I needed them to add decorative corners to my border.

In this new design I need to add a decorative element only in the center of the top and bottom borders (see attachment). I reviewed the border-image documentation and not sure that it can actually do what I need. Or am I wrong? If in fact border-image can't do that type of border, but you have some other ideas how to accomplish this - please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this. This is what you probably want to do http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/border-images/

Comment: Thanks, but that tutorial doesn't really address this particular style of border I'm trying to do. As with all other tutorials and articles on CSS border image I viewed they show how to achieve all around border or have something in the corners. In my case I have a center piece while everything else is just a line. So I wasn't sure if I'm not getting some aspect of CSS3 border-image or if it is just no possible at this point.